# Adding less support to a production webpack configuration (from Facebook's create-react-app)

Tags: css, less, webpack-style-loader

I have forked (or `eject`ed) off Facebook's [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) project, with the requirement to add a few additional tools (e.g. testing, redux, less etc.), and the perhaps naive assumption that straying a bit off the path wouldn't be too much of a problem.

I think I have just about managed to add less using the following `webpack.config.dev.js`:

```
//......
module: {
preLoaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'eslint',
    include: paths.appSrc,
  }
],
loaders: [
  // Process JS with Babel.
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: require('./babel.dev')
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css!postcss'
  },
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: 'style!css!postcss!less'
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json'
  },
  //......
  }
]
},//.....
```

I have left the CSS loader in there (perhaps incorrectly) so that I can bring in the react/bootstrap library. Perhaps there is a better way of doing this.

Anyway, I am confused about how to add a pre-processor into `webpack.config.prod.js`. Here is a snippet (with Facebook's helpful comments):

```
loaders: [
  // Process JS with Babel.
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: require('./babel.prod')
  },
  // The notation here is somewhat confusing.
  // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
  // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
  // "style" loader normally turns CSS into JS modules injecting <style>,
  // but unlike in development configuration, we do something different.
  // `ExtractTextPlugin` first applies the "postcss" and "css" loaders
  // (second argument), then grabs the result CSS and puts it into a
  // separate file in our build process. This way we actually ship
  // a single CSS file in production instead of JS code injecting <style>
  // tags. If you use code splitting, however, any async bundles will still
  // use the "style" loader inside the async code so CSS from them won't be
  // in the main CSS file.
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    // "?-autoprefixer" disables autoprefixer in css-loader itself:
    // https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/281
    // We already have it thanks to postcss. We only pass this flag in
    // production because "css" loader only enables autoprefixer-powered
    // removal of unnecessary prefixes when Uglify plugin is enabled.
    // Webpack 1.x uses Uglify plugin as a signal to minify *all* the assets
    // including CSS. This is confusing and will be removed in Webpack 2:
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/283
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?-autoprefixer!postcss')
    // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
  },
```

How can I add a less pre-processor step in a stable and performant way?

For context my `index.js` imports look as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import { CommentsSectionContainer } from './components/CommentsSection';
import './index.less';
```

Answer (score 1):

Install less and less-loader from npm or yarn:

```
npm install --save-dev less less-loader
```

Follow this link to install extract-text-webkit-plugin:

https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin

First you need to add the loader in the loaders array, after css probably makes sense for readability. It will look like this:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/, 
  loader:  ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")
}
```

Then initialize the plugin in the plugins array:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
```

Thaaaaaat should do it with another `yarnpkg start`